# Linksys firmware versions?

Tags: firmware, wrt54g

I have a Linksys WRT54G and wanted to see if there was any updated firmware available.

According to the device, it's running 4.30.13 build 16, date Jul. 1, 2008.

The [Linksys support site](http://homesupport.cisco.com/en-us/wireless/lbc/WRT54G/download) says the latest version of the firmware (for v3) is 4.21.4, dated 08/18/2011.

While the date is newer, it seems like the version is older.  Can anyone explain the linksys firmware version scheme?  Is 4.21 newer than 4.30?

Answer (score 0):

There are various different models of the router you are referring to, so it might be that the versions and their dates are for different models.  There are more than eight different versions of the WRT54G.

However, you will get far better results with your router if you use a third party firmware like [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index)

Check for your version in the router database.  It will make you happier than trying to get it working well with linksys software (no they don't do a better job than third party firmware creators as they have little interest in maintaining firmware for old routers).

Comment: also, not all of them run the same OS. If its a GL or V4, it runs linux, v5 onwards run vxworks